# generating POJOs from JSON Schema for non-object types

Tags: java, json, code-generation, jsonschema

I am trying to generate POJOs from the JSON Schema of XMBC.
I do this with [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).
However, nothing gets generated. It doesn't even bring me an error.

This is a reduced sample json schema I am trying to generate from:

```
{
  "description": "JSON-RPC API of XBMC",
  "id": "http://xbmc.org/jsonrpc/ServiceDescription.json",
  "methods": {
    "Addons.ExecuteAddon": {
      "description": "Executes the given addon with the given parameters (if possible)",
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "addonid",
          "required": true,
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "default": "",
          "name": "params",
          "type": [
            {
              "additionalProperties": {
                "default": "",
                "type": "string"
              },
              "type": "object"
            },
            {
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "type": "array"
            },
            {
              "description": "URL path (must start with / or ?",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "default": false,
          "name": "wait",
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      ],
      "returns": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "type": "method"
    }
  },
  "notifications": {
    "Application.OnVolumeChanged": {
      "description": "The volume of the application has changed.",
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "sender",
          "required": true,
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "data",
          "properties": {
            "muted": {
              "required": true,
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "volume": {
              "maximum": 100,
              "minimum": 0,
              "required": true,
              "type": "integer"
            }
          },
          "required": true,
          "type": "object"
        }
      ],
      "returns": null,
      "type": "notification"
    }
  },
  "types": {
    "Addon.Content": {
      "default": "unknown",
      "enums": [
        "unknown",
        "video",
        "audio",
        "image",
        "executable"
      ],
      "id": "Addon.Content",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "version": "6.14.3"
}
```

I must admin that my knowledge of JSON is very terse, maybe it is just a simple fault of mine. But can anyone help me how I can generate Java objects from such a JSON Schema?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON Schema doesn't support method. JSON schema defines json data structure, it would not be used to define your methods. Most important attribute in JSON schema is `properties`.

It's good to generate POJO data models from a JSON schema, but not business logic. You can learn the JSON schema from [those examples](http://json-schema.org/examples.html).